# What is Optimal Control Theory and Controllability Theory?

Tags: variational-principle, variational-calculus, optimization

I was exploring the methods to analyze the evolution of a system from one quantum state to another using a suitable Hamiltonian. Some searching led me to the keywords [Controllability Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability) and [Optimal Control Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control). Although both these topics are concepts in Mathematics, please try to answer my questions with a quantum mechanical perspective.

What is it which we try to optimize using Optimal Control Theory?

Given an initial quantum system (say a superposition of many states), and the final state we want to reach using some unitary transformation, is it possible to calculate the minimum (optimal) time required in the time-evolution? If yes, a working example would be of great help to me.

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia? Optimal control means optimizing a system, but the other term is "control theory", whereas "Controllability" is complementary to "observability".

Comment: Optimal control theory is not a quantum theory per se.

Comment: I doubt anyone on phys.SE will answer this for you, they don't know the answer and will complain that your question isn't about "physics". I would try instead to ask this question on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The quantum equivalent to the optimal control of densities is a topic of interest in the areas of large population control, optimal mass transport and mean field games (try https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06064) in the control theory. The idea in the related literature is to *transport* a density given the individual micro-dynamics. The question of the minimum time required will depend on the available control authority and can technically be driven to zero, given an unbounded control authority.