# For any unitary $U = e^{iA}$, question about the matrix element $A_{pq}$ of matrix $A$ and its functional derivative

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, quantum-computer, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Any unitary operation $U \in U(N)$ can be represented as $U = e^{iA}$, where $A$ is an arbitrary $N \times N$ Hermitian matrix. In the case of a time-independent Hamiltonian $H$, we have $A = -itH$ (thus $U = e^{-iHt}$), which corresponds to a unitary operator generated by $H$ for an evolution time $t$. For the time-dependent case, $A$ becomes more complex and is expressed in terms of a time-ordered exponential.

My question is about the matrix element of $A$, denoted as $A_{pq}$. Assuming I can always find a Hamiltonian $H$ (or $H(t)$) that can generate any unitary operator $U \in U(N)$, does this imply that each matrix element $A_{pq}$ of $A$ must possess a unique functional dependence on $H$ (or $H(t)$)?

The origin of my question lies in [this Science report paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1093649) about quantum optimal control landscapes. Particularly, the question is essentially related to the transition from Eq.(2) to (3) there. The main argument they present is as follows: First, consider a time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$ that depends on a control field $C(t)$. The unitary operator $U$ is generated by this Hamiltonian, indicating that $U$ is also a functional of $C(t)$. The cost function, which is the functional derivative of the transition probability from state $\lvert i \rangle$ to $\lvert f \rangle$ (i.e., $\lvert \langle i \rvert U \lvert f \rangle \rvert^2 = \lvert U_{if} \rvert^2$) with respect to $C(t)$, is denoted as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta \lvert U_{if}\rvert^2}{\delta C(t)}.
\end{equation} The paper then makes use of the fact that $U = e^{iA}$ where $A$ is an arbitrary Hermitian matrix, and therefore, $U_{if} = \langle i \rvert U \rvert f \rangle = \langle i \rvert e^{iA} \lvert f \rangle$, leading to the expression

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta \lvert U_{if} \rvert^2}{\delta C(t)} = \sum_{p,q} \frac{\partial \lvert U_{if} \rvert^2}{\partial A_{pq}} \frac{\delta A_{pq}}{\delta C(t)}.
\end{equation}

The argument they then rely on is that each matrix element $A_{pq}[C(t)]$ of $A$ must be independently addressable, implying that each $A_{pq}[C(t)]$ should have a unique functional dependence on $C(t)$ based on the "controllability assumption" they introduced earlier. Therefore, they claimed that the set of functions $\{\delta A_{pq}/\delta C(t)\}$ are linearly independent for all $p,q,$ and $t$. As I understood from Eq.(1), the controllability assumption essentially states that there exists at least one control field $C(t)$ such that $\lvert U_{if} \rvert^2 = 1$ corresponds to $\frac{\delta \lvert U_{if} \rvert^2}{\delta C(t)} = 0$ for all time $t \in [0, T]$. However, I don't fully understand how such arguments put together to get such conclusion. I'd be greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide any insight and explanation. I know my question tends to compress a lot of things all at once, so please feel free to leave any question or comment for any clarification.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I find the question very unclear. What do you want to know, in simple terms? Which is the point that is puzzling you?

Comment: @Quillo hey, thanks for the comment. Denote an arbitrary unitary $U = e^{iA}$, where $A$ is an arbitrary Hermitian matrix. $U$ is generated by Hamiltonian $H(t)$, which depends on some control function $C(t)$. For example, $H(t) = C(t)H$ where $H$ is some Hermitian matrix. Then, I am curious to know under what condition each matrix element $A_{pq}$ of $A$ can be independently addressable, i.e. a set of functions $\{ \delta A_{pq}/ \delta C(t) \}$ are linearly independent for all $p,q$.

Comment: @Quillo It seems like in the paper, such condition is when there always exists $C(t)$ such that $U[C(t)]$ can produce any target state $\lvert f \rangle$. It roughly makes sense to me because if so, then every $N^2$ matrix elements of $A$ can be generated independently by $C(t)$. However, I want to see it more rigorously. Also, if so, then doesn't it also imply that every $N^2$ matrix elements of $U$ can also be addressed independently by $C(t)$? I'm not sure about the relationship between the matrix element of $A$ or $U$ and the quantum state that it can generate/reach.

Comment: I think your question is mostly about scrutinising a (sloppy but well-motivated) physical argument related to an integral of a matrix and then about its imaginary exponential. It might be better answered in Maths.SE under Lie groups.

Comment: @JonMegan I totally agree with your concerns, the paper is very unclear and it seems that this point is not discussed at all! I posted a very incomplete answer, I hope it could be somehow useful to other interested people.

Comment: Thank you. I also left a comment regarding my opinion about the concern. It somehow makes sense, but as you have stated below, I don't think the paper addressed this point clearly enough.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** This is NOT a satisfactory answer, as I feel that I am missing some possibly important point! However, the question is delicate and technical and I hope that this starting point could help
> someone else to provide a better answer (or an interested reader to
> study the problem). For an introduction to quantum control, see [Quantum control Landscapes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.0684) (from the same authors of the paper discussed in this post) or the links [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150749/226902).

The analysis in [Quantum Optimally Controlled Transition Landscapes](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1093649) is restricted to quantum systems with a **finite number** $N$ of possible states (the Hilbert space is just a finite-dimensional vector space). The fundamental *assumption* is that the entire $N$-dimensional Hilbert space is just the "controllable" portion of a possibly larger system that also contains states that are not addressed by the control.

**Quantum control -** In this context, "[quantum control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_control#Optimal_control)" means that we want to maximize the probability $P_{if}=|U_{if}|^2$ to transition from an initial state
$|i\rangle$ to a chosen final state $|f\rangle$, where $U_{if}=\langle i|U|f \rangle \in U(N)$ is a $N\times N$ unitary matrix.
The time evolution operator $U=U[C(t)]$ is a functional of the control function $C(t)$: typically one adds to the Hamiltonian $H_0$ an external field that depends on $C(t)$. The goal is to maximize the chance to transition to a desired state $|f\rangle$ by choosing the best $C(t)$.
In other terms, the whole point is to maximize $P_{if}[C]$ with respect to $C(t)$ by considering the functional derivative $\delta P_{if}[C]/\delta C(t)$. In most cases, $A= \int_0^T dt (H_0+C(t) f)$, where $f$ is a suitable operator that models experimental control methodology (i.e. a "Dirac-delta" version of more general kernel operators, see [equation 2.1c here](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.37.4950)). More generally you should have a T-ordered exp.

**Notation -** The paper proceeds by saying that it is more convenient to introduce the generator $A$, $U=\exp(iA)$ with $A^\dagger = A$. Therefore, $A$ is an Hermitian $N\times N$ matrix.
Since we have $N$ independent states, call $|q\rangle$ a basis of our Hilbert space ($q=1...N$), so that $|f \rangle = \sum_{q=1}^N|q \rangle \langle q|f \rangle $ and similarly for $|i \rangle$. Hence, $A_{pq} = \langle p|A|q \rangle$ is the matrix element on this basis ($p$ is just another index to label the $N$ basis states of the Hilbert space).

**Controllability -** We can write $\delta P_{if}[C]/\delta C(t)$ in terms of $A$ via simple calculation, as described in the question:

$$
\dfrac{P_{if}[C]}{\delta C(t)} = \sum_{p,q} \frac{\partial \lvert U_{if} \rvert^2}{\partial A_{pq}} \frac{\delta A_{pq}}{\delta C(t)}
$$

This equation in terms of $A$ turns out to be convenient and useful if the only way of having $\dfrac{P_{if}[C]}{\delta C(t)} =0$ is that $\frac{\partial \lvert U_{if} \rvert^2}{\partial A_{pq}}=0$ for all $p,q$!

Therefore, it seems to me that there is nothing particularly deep: the authors just claim that it is possible to make all the (not well motivated IMO) assumptions they need to guarantee this fact, e.g. "the set of functions $\delta A_{pq}/\delta C(t)$ for $p,q=1...N$ are all linearly independent (whatever this means)" and $A=\sum_{q,p}|p\rangle A_{pq}[C(t)]\langle q|$ is an element of a Hermitian operator, at each time $t$ (namely, time dependence does not spoil the good properties of $A$).

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I am not sure if I understand the first paragraph properly. What do you mean by "-dimensional Hilbert space is just the "controllable" portion of a possibly larger system"?

Comment: I also believe that this assumption is not well-explained. I have thought about it deeper and now it at least makes sense that every matrix element of $A$ should be independent with respect to $C(t)$. This is because we produce every $2^N$ computational basis states: $\lvert 00 \cdots 00 \rangle, \dotsc, \lvert 11 \cdots 11\rangle$. Since this is a (sub)set of basis for any $U$, it kind of makes sense that every element matrix of $U$ can be independently addressable w.r.t $C(t)$, and so thus $A$ ($A$ is hermitian, so matrix element of $A$ must be directly related to $U = e^{iA}$).

Comment: @JonMegan it means that typically the Hilbert space is much larger and, possibly, uncontrollable (it is infinite-dimensional). However, there may be a finite number $N$ of (orthogonal) states that can be reached ("prepared") via experimental techniques. Therefore, the analysis is restricted to this subspace (or to spin systems that are naturally finite dimensional.. or an ensemble of Q-bits).